# How to unselect a class when clicking on another class with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a map of the US with selectable counties that when clicked change their background to red. What I want to happen is when the user clicks on another county it deselects the current county and then selects the new one only. Currently right now when clicking on the county class it changes the class which gives it a background of red, but when you click another county then both are red.

Here is the code where I draw the map and change classes when clicked:

```
        //DRAW MAP
        d3.json("js/map.json", function(error, mapData){
            if (error) throw error;
            //draw counties
            edit.map.append("g")
                .selectAll("path")
                .data(topojson.feature(mapData, mapData.objects.counties).features)
                .enter().append("path")
                .attr("class", "counties")
                .attr("d", edit.path)
                .on("click", function(d){
                    sFips = d.properties.STATEFP;
                    cFips = d.properties.COUNTYFP;

                    //display values in text boxes
                    $("#locationCountySelect").val(cFips);
                    $("#locationStateSelect").val(sFips);

                    //change clicked county class name                  
                    if (this.className.baseVal == "counties") {
                        this.className.baseVal = "selectedCounty";
                        //send new county to db
                    } else {
                        this.className.baseVal = "counties";
                    }
              });
         });
```

Again, how can I only have one county selected at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this purpose I suggest you ditch jQuery in favor of D3. The following two lines in your `click` listener will do the job:

```
d3.select(".selectedCounty").attr("class", "counties");
d3.select(this).attr("class", "selectedCounty");
```

The first statement selects the element having class `.selectedCounty` and sets the `class` attribute to `counties` instead. The second one selects the element clicked upon and set its class to `selectedCounty`.

It might also be worth considering to keep a reference to the currently selected element in a variable in the outer scope to not having to reselect on every click:

```
var selectedCounty = d3.select(".selectedCounty");

edit.map.append("g")
// ...
  .on("click", function(d) {
    selectedCounty.attr("class", "counties");
    selectedCounty = d3.select(this).attr("class", "selectedCounty");
  }
```

As requested by Teton-Coder's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512130/how-to-unselect-a-class-when-clicking-on-another-class-with-javascript/42512488?noredirect=1#comment72253166_42512488) there might be the need to toggle the class instead of just replacing it. Using `selection.attr("class", "selectedCounty")` will set the value of the `class` attribute, whereby replacing any other classes set on the element. Although you are allowed to pass a space-separated list to the attribute via this function the easiest way to toggle a specific class on an element is the use of [`selection.classed()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_classed). The second argument to that function is a boolean value determining if the class should either be assigned to the element or be removed from it while leaving all other classes intact. The above code can thus be rewritten as:

```
var selectedCounty = d3.select(".selectedCounty");

edit.map.append("g")
// ...
  .on("click", function(d) {
    selectedCounty.classed("selectedCounty", false);
    selectedCounty = d3.select(this).classed("selectedCounty", true);
  }
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! The first one worked like a charm. The second one didn't work.

Comment: Please, give the second one another try. I edited it to avoid a null value when first clicked. I'd prefer the second solution as it is superior to the first one.

Comment: If I have multiple classes for each county and not all are the same classes for each county, how could I capture those other classes and put them back when removing the selectedCounty class? Is that possible?

Comment: @Teton-Coder I added another variation making use of `selection.classed()` which will do what you requested in your comment. When first writing my answer, this came to my mind, but I opted against it to stay as close to your original question as possible. However, I'd consider this last approach the most common one.

Comment: You are a life saver! Much appreciated!!